# How to create Public String property with drop-down list of options?

Tags: c#, string, properties, collections

Is it possible to attach a List of strings to a String property so that the user can select one of the strings from the Properties window?  Should I implement ICollection or something of that sort?

Comment: One more question:  Is there any way for me to pass an argument to the TypeConverter constructor when using it as an attribute?  I want to be able to use this attribute to be able to create a string drop-down list property in any class using a List<String> provided by the user..so it doesn't work to just set a default list of Strings in the TypeConverter class.

Comment: You should mark something as an answer here, then ask a new question, since this is opening a new topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to restrict a property to one of a few specific options, you should use an Enum instead of a String for the property.

If you want to provide defaults, but let them type any string in and ignore the defaults, then you can use StringConverter.  For details, read [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Property Grid control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx).  It covers this exact scenario.

Comment: I checked that link out but it appears that it tells you how to do it for a PropertyGrid object - I can't get this to work in my design-time Properties window.  Everything I've found seems to be for a PropertyGrid control - is there any way to do this at design time?

Comment: That's the same thing.  The design time properties windows IS a PropertyGrid control - if you do what it's describing, it will display that way at design time.

Comment: Thank you this worked...I accidentally had the wrong type in my Attribute (had StringConverter but my class name was ColumnStringConverter, so it wasn't working).

Comment: It would be nice for once if people actually answered the question instead of telling us how it should be done. Having the property as an enum instead of a string isn't always going to work. Take the HyperLink class' Target property for example. It is (necessarily) a string, but in design mode it has a pre-defined list of options, e.g. "_blank", "_parent" etc.

Answer (score 4):

No. You should create an `enum` type with your string choices, and make the property of that type. Example:

```
public enum Choices
{
    NiceChoice,
    PoorChoice
}

public class Chooser
{
    public Choices Choice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I can't use an enum because the list is dynamically generated.  Basically when the user sets the datasource for a DataGridView, the property is going to read the column names and populate the list with those names.  The user will then be able to select which column they want to filter.